# How to put an image in an ImageView from the Activity not the XML file?

Tags: android

What I am trying to do is put multiple images without the out of memory problem so I'm using the method PutImage() and trying to put the image in the ImageView but from the Activity not the XML file

**Here is my XML code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"       android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="false">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**And here is the activity**

```
public class RecipeBanana extends Activity {
ImageView v;
Button button;
Context localcontext = null;     
public static Drawable getAssetImage(Context context, String filename) throws IOException {
AssetManager assets = context.getResources().getAssets();
InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream((assets.open("drawable/" + filename + ".jpg")));
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer);
return new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
}


public void PutImage(ImageView v, String x){

    try {
        v.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromStream(localcontext.getAssets().open("flags/" + x + ".jpg"), null));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}


    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_banana);

        ImageView v=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        PutImage(v,"bananarecipe");
        addListenerOnButton();

    }
```

Comment: where you are initializing `localcontext` ?

Comment: In the fourth line of the activity

Comment: means you are initializing `localcontext` with `null`. just add `localcontext=RecipeBanana.this` before calling `getAssetImage` method or after `setContentView` in `onCreate` method of RecipeBanana Activity

Comment: Still not working .. it gives me an empty window as if um not giving it a src for the image

Comment: do you ever call `getAssetImage()`

Comment: @FoamyGuy : you are also right OP is not calling `getAssetImage()` and also not initializing `localcontext`

Comment: I don't know where to call getAssetImage() and I initialized localcontext as @FoamyGuy said

Answer (score 0):

You aren't ever calling getAssetImage() so you don't need that method, remove it. You don't need to create a variable to hold a reference to the context. Activity *is a* context so you are allowed to call `getAssets()` directly without needing to put anything in front of it.

Try like this:

```
public class RecipeBanana extends Activity {
    ImageView v;
    Button button; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_banana);
        ImageView v=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        PutImage(v,"bananarecipe");
        addListenerOnButton();
    }
    public void PutImage(ImageView v, String filename){
        try {
            v.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open("flags/" + filename + ".jpg"), null));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Using this code if you have a file called `bananarecipe.jpg` inside of `assets/flags/` then it should load into your ImageView.